# Endless Infinite Scrollview

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview, scrollview

Is there anyway to produce a vertical scroll view that will have the illusion of an endless continuous scroll?

Apple has released sample code for something called StreetScroller that does this for a horizontal scrollview but can this be reproduced for a vertical one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [This](https://github.com/caesarcat/InfinitePagingView) it is a great control the allows horizontal and vertical infinite scrolling.